# Alignment in ebproof

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, logic

I'm trying to typeset sequent proofs using the `ebproof` package. This package uses `&` to align sequents vertically. I'm trying to write a command that produces a full sequent, including the alignment mark, so I can change sequent styling in one place and have it work throughout my document.

Here's an example that works to produce the sort of thing I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebproof}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{prooftree}
\Hypo{\Gamma &| \Delta, A}
\Infer1{\Gamma, \neg A &| \Delta}
\end{prooftree}
\]

\end{document}
```

This works fine, and aligns the two sequents at the `|`. On the other hand, the following does not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebproof}

\newcommand{\sqq}[2]{#1 &| #2}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{prooftree}
\Hypo{\sqq{\Gamma}{\Delta, A}}
\Infer1{\sqq{\Gamma, \neg A}{\Delta}}
\end{prooftree}
\]

\end{document}
```

It gives the error `Misplaced alignment tab character` in the line `\Hypo{\sqq{\Gamma}{\Delta, A}}`. But this should be basically the same as the first, working, example, as far as I can see.

`\protect` and `\DeclareRobustCommand` don't seem to help, although I don't understand them, so it's possible I'm not trying them correctly.

Comment: Welcome! Why exactly do you want to do this? I ask because I don't think that you can do it this way, but you might be able to achieve the same goal using a different approach. In particular, how does this help to ensure consistency? Why not just define `\newcommand*\dralignmark{|}` or whatever?

Comment: It helps to ensure consistency because I can just type `\sqq{X}{Y}` throughout my document and decide in a single line at the top how a sequent with left part `X` and right part `Y` is to appear. For the purposes of my MWE, this isn't much different from just doing `\leftpart{X} & \rightpart{Y}` or something like that; but I often want to typeset sequents that are more involved, and not have to decide in advance what belongs on the left and what on the right.

Comment: But if you write `\mymacro{leftpart}{rightpart}` you must decide in advance what goes on the left and what on the right. I don't see how your syntax would avoid your having to decide on that splitting point in advance. What you do with the left and right parts is a different matter, but you're still tied to the content of each.

Comment: For example, I might want the antecedent to appear above the consequent, or to the right. If I use the arguments in a two-argument command to distinguish logical roles, then the positions associated with those logical roles can vary. 

The example that I was actually working on when I came across this issue involved sequents with four places, and so a command with four arguments; currently I'm representing these sequents with 2x2 grids, but I don't want to commit to that appearance for them so early in the writing process.

Comment: I can see that, but I don't see any easy way to implement it. Maybe somebody else will think of something, but `ebproof` is really not designed in a way which would make this straightforward. You could probably define different commands and do it that way e.g. have `\DRHyper...` pass its arguments off to `\Hyper...` with the appropriate alignment markers inserted, but `\Hyper` etc. really rely on finding those markers as far as I can see.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing at the moment. It still leaves me building the sequent in three separate places (alone plus two wrapper commands for `ebproofs`), but it's the best I've been able to figure out. After your comments, I tried mucking around with `expandafter`, in the hopes that I could get the `&` to be a `&` by the time `ebproofs` commands look at it, but I couldn't get anything different to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a command defined as you've suggested because the package parses specifically looking for `&`s in the arguments given to `\Hypo`, `\Infer` etc.

To ensure consistency, I suggest defining two commands: one for a partial sequent and one for the alignment mark.

```
\newcommand*\dram{|}
\newcommand*\partsq[1]{#1}
```

Obviously, the second just repeats its argument, but I assume your thought is that you might want it to do something else.

Then you can write

```
\[
  \begin{prooftree}
    \Hypo{\partsq{\Gamma} &\dram \partsq{\Delta, A}}
    \Infer1{\partsq{\Gamma, \neg A} &\dram \partsq{\Delta}}
  \end{prooftree}
\]
```

to produce

[image: aligned sequents]

As far as I can see there is no neat trick available here, so the alternative would involve rewriting a substantial part of `ebproof` to the point that you would probably be better advised to simply write an alternative package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\newcommand*\dram{|}
\newcommand*\partsq[1]{#1}
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{prooftree}
    \Hypo{\partsq{\Gamma} &\dram \partsq{\Delta, A}}
    \Infer1{\partsq{\Gamma, \neg A} &\dram \partsq{\Delta}}
  \end{prooftree}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's really helpful to hear even "you can't do that"; I was convinced I was missing something obvious!